# Best way to transfer mixed unicode and single byte characters over boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

We're trying to use winapi widestring functions to retrieve registry information.  We then need to transfer that information across the network.

```
LPWSTR PerfData = (LPWSTR) malloc(8192);
RegQueryValueEx(hSubKey, TEXT("DisplayName"), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) PerfData, &cbData);
```

Now that we have the widestring characters we will be padding them with xml in single byte characters.  It is important to save as much bandwidth as possible because as this iterates over thousands of computers it already clogged our network when we were using the single bytes.

Also, how am I going to separate these on the other side?

Comment: How are they padded - if clogging the network I suspect you need to look at the messages rather than just cut size by less than half

Comment: Bare minimum xml padding.  My main concern is to not clog it any further by having double byte characters for the xml where it need not be.  Double byte characters are okay for the value data.  I want to be able to transfer both over as I see fit and have both the server and the client know what I'm sending.

Comment: Could you use UTF8? 1 byte for USASCII, multi-byte for more exotic cards. You'd need to know the rough distribution of characters you send to know if it's a win.

Comment: Run some compression (gzip say) over the XML?

Comment: If you're using XML, you've already admitted that bandwidth isn't a concern. All those `</namespace::tagname>` end tags are a bigger issue than an occasional double-byte character.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest (in terms of bandwidth) protocol I've used so far was Google's [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).
I strongly recommend it. As for boost-asio, it's not causing any overhead - asio is a good choice. You can also consider compressing it (use [boost iostreams gzip filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html) with asio).

Comment: Okay.  Still the main questions is how do I send this mixed data and have the server know which is which?

Comment: why not use utf8? the encoding decoding will be automatic - this is exactly why utf8 was invented. Is that an option?

Comment: Also if you use compression I'm not sure that it will matter much. Gzip can reduce the total size of a char stream up to 20-40x. Is the XML mandatory? It will bloat your data for sure.